# Php Svn Client Solution

Tags: php, svn

i've a php project under svn.

No problems in development: i've my own https svn server and a can commit/update from my localhost without any problem.

Now i have to put that project into a free hosting space that does not have svn. But there i need only the checkout/update function, i don't need to commit or do any other thing from there.

So i've searched for something that implement the checkout/update in pure php and i've founded this solution:

https://code.google.com/p/phpsvnclient/

I've tried the example proposed with their repository and the checkout works fine. But when i try to checkout my project the operation fails: error in http request (svn credentials are setted correctly).

So is there another solution to reach my goal? Maybe a newer project more supported?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Changing the repository URL from **httpS** to just **http** solved for me.